# sum collection in laravel

Tags: laravel, sum

How can I sum `sessions` value of this array?

```
Collection {#3646 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "type" => "New Visitor"
      "sessions" => 154
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "type" => "Returning Visitor"
      "sessions" => 59
    ]
  ]
}
```

## Code

```
$analyticsData4 = Analytics::fetchUserTypes(Period::months(1));
```

this code return my dd above. I need to sum sessions value of `New Visitors and Returning Visitors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

```
$totalUsers = $analyticsData4->sum(function ($analyticsData4) {
  return $analyticsData4['sessions'];
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just convert your collection to Json like following,

```
$json = $analyticsData4->toJson();
```

Then, use this package [jsonq](https://github.com/nahid/jsonq) to sum/count/size/traverse/find whatever you want quite easily.

For example,

```
$q = new Jsonq('data.json');
$res = $q->from('products')
->where('cat', '=', 1)
->sum('price');
```

Note, this might look a lots work for this simple problem but certainly it will help you across the project.

Comment: it already solved but that package is something to consider for future coding, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper for that, you just use `sum` like the following.

```
$analyticsData4->sum('sessions');
```

You can read more about Laravel Collection [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sum).

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely will look into it